# Audiotrack Can't stop playback immediately

Tags: android

Developer docs says that i must call Pause() then Flush()(for discard playback data).

But that doesn't work.

I've found out that if i add small delay between AudioTrack.Pause() and AudioTrack.Flush() calls. Sound playback stops almost immediately, but sometimes it doesn't work.

So how to stop audiotrack immediately?